# Slicing characters from string (flutter)

Tags: flutter, dart

When a number is longer than 4 or more characters, I want to replace the last number(s) with 'k'. The final value should also be converted to a string. TIA!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
final value = 54325342534.toString();
  print(value.replaceRange(3, value.length, 'k' * (value.length - 3)));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this using the Right Pad concept with [`padRight`](https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.17.3/dart-core/String/padRight.html) method in the `String` class:

Example:

```
String formatNumber(int number) {
  final numberAsString = number.toString();
  return numberAsString.substring(0, 4).padRight(numberAsString.length, 'k');
}
```

And use it like the following, let's try the value 123456789:

```
void main() {
  final number = 123456789;
  print(formatNumber(number));
}
```

Output:

```
1234kkkkk
```